# Logistic regression in Python: GridSearchCV not working

Tags: python, logistic-regression, data-mining, hyperparameters, tfidfvectorizer

I am a bit new to data mining and especially to text analytics. I am training a logistic regression model on my dataset and I am trying to get the best accuracy possible, at least around 0,6. But I can't seem to go even higher than 0,5.
Here are my datasets :

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpedroni/DMML2021_Microsoft/main/data/training_data.csv')
df_pred = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpedroni/DMML2021_Microsoft/main/data/unlabelled_test_data.csv')
```

I trained my model using a pipeline with a tfidf :

```
tfidf_params = dict(sublinear_tf= True, 
                       min_df = 4, 
                       norm= 'l2', 
                       ngram_range= (1,4),
                       tokenizer= word_tokenize)

clf = Pipeline(steps=[
('features', TfidfVectorizer(**tfidf_params)),
('model', LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs', max_iter=300))
])

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
def metrics(y_test, y_pred):
  precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None)
  recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None)
  f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None)
  print("Precision: " + str(precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')))
  print("Recall: " + str(recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')))
  print("F1: " + str(2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)))
  print("Accuracy: " + str(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))

metrics(y_test, y_pred)
```

I get an accuracy score of `0.471875`but I want to make it higher and so tried to do a grid search like so :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid_lr = {
    'max_iter': [20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],                      
    'solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],   
    'class_weight': ['balanced']                                    
}

logModel_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=LogisticRegression(random_state=1234), param_grid=param_grid_lr, verbose=1, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
logModel_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(logModel_grid.best_estimator_)
```

However I get this error that I don't understand : `ValueError: could not convert string to float`. I get this error for this line `logModel_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)` but I don't get this error for the log model before doing the grid search. Would you know why doing a `GridSearchCV` would bring this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your vectorizer in the estimator.

Assuming you processed it like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpedroni/DMML2021_Microsoft/main/data/training_data.csv')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['sentence'],df['difficulty'],
                                                    test_size=0.2, random_state=30, stratify=df['difficulty'])
```

We use the pipeline like your first part:

```
tfidf_params = dict(sublinear_tf= True, 
                       min_df = 4, 
                       norm= 'l2', 
                       ngram_range= (1,4),
                       tokenizer= word_tokenize)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
('features', TfidfVectorizer(**tfidf_params)),
('model', LogisticRegression())
])
```

Define params, not the underscore :

```
param_grid_lr = {
    'model__max_iter': [20, 50],                      
    'model__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs'],   
    'model__class_weight': ['balanced']                                    
}
```

Fit:

```
logModel_grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid_lr, verbose=1, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
logModel_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: you can see which parameters give you a better score. Sorry don't quite get your question

Comment: It works ! I don't have an error anymore, however I get the same accuracy score as before. Is there a way to improve that score ?

Comment: No I get that as an output `Fitting 10 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 40 fits
Precision: 0.471875
Recall: 0.471875
F1: [0.57225434 0.4248366  0.4495114  0.42038217 0.42767296 0.52279635]
Accuracy: 0.471875`

Comment: I don't think it's the model. It might be that you have to tune your vectorizer, basically your input. Sorry I am not familiar with your data and this is not the question you asked